# Clean out, or reset test-database with Rspec and MongoID on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, mongoid

When I run my rspec tests, many fail due to stale data in my mongodb database. AFAIK it is far better to test with a clean database.

With mysql, I could run `rake db:test:prepare` to clean up the database. How can I clean nd/or re-seed the database before each test?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using MongoID you can use [Database Cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) with **Truncation** strategy. E.g.:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Answer (score 31):

Neither of the other answers work for me with **Mongoid 3.0**.  I used @Batkins answer modified like so

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  # Clean/Reset Mongoid DB prior to running each test.
  config.before(:each) do
    Mongoid::Sessions.default.collections.select {|c| c.name !~ /system/ }.each(&:drop)
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to empty the collection but don't want to drop it (maybe you have indexes or something), do this

```
Mongoid::Sessions.default.collections.select {|c| c.name !~ /system/}.each {|c| c.find.remove_all}
```

Comment: Sorry. I commented on the reply above without seeing your answer. Upvoted as `Mongoid::Sessions.default` works just as fine as `Mongoid.default_session`.

Comment: @Alessandro - Thanks, I didn't know about Mongoid.default_session

Answer (score 19):

IMHO, This is a much nicer solution than installing a gem for the specific purpose of cleaning out your database....  3 lines to go in your spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  #Other config stuff goes here

  # Clean/Reset Mongoid DB prior to running the tests
  config.before :each do
    Mongoid.master.collections.select {|c| c.name !~ /system/ }.each(&:drop)
  end
end
```

Credit: [A user named Alex posted this as a solution for a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688140/how-to-do-proper-database-testing-tdd-on-rails-3-using-mongdb-through-mongoid/4699029#4699029)

Comment: If you're using **Mongoid 3**, you will need something like:

`Mongoid.default_session.collections.select {|c| c.name !~ /system/ }.each(&:drop)`

Comment: This is totally nitpicky and really probably doesn't matter at all but your solution is a little inefficient. You are iterating over all the collections once for the select and then over the subset in the each. 

This just iterates over the collections once:


`Mongoid.default_session.collections.each { |coll| coll.drop unless /^system/.match(coll.name) }`

Answer (score 12):

In Mongoid v2.0.2

```
before(:each) do
    Mongoid.purge!
end
```

[Rdoc: Mongoid.purge!](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Config%3apurge!)

Comment: Didn't work when I tried the selected answer, there were still some records that was created somehow, this helped me. And the tests are notably faster as a result somehow too.

Comment: i think you want Mongoid::Config.purge!

Comment: `Mongoid.purge!` works for me with 4.0.2 and I think it is better than using DatabaseCleaner.

Answer (score 3):

add to gemfile:

```
gem 'database_cleaner', :github => 'bmabey/database_cleaner'
```

run `bundle install`

add this to your spec_helper:

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :truncation
  DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].clean_with(:truncation)
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

full credit goes to:
http://blog.codelette.com/2013/07/07/make-rspec-clean-up-mongoid-records/

Comment: Why did you just delete your question about the class variables?  It was a good one, and I have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you using with multiple MongoDB clients, or you don't work with the default client, for example, you create a new client in mongoid.yml like: 'actions'.

you need to specify the connection name.
for example for 'actions' client use:

```
config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid, { connection: :actions }].start
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid, { connection: :actions }].clean
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```